顔見れる actual meaning?

The character is explaining why he hasn't show visited his friend for a while after some awkward stuff happened between them.
About 顔見れる is to take as "show my face" or more like "Look  them in the face"? and could it be reworded as 見られる?

顔見れる is to take as "show my face" -- "show my face" would be 顔見せる, no?

見れる is the ら抜き version of 見られる, which means "can see". It never means "to show" regardless of the context.

見える = 見られる = 見れる※ = can see
※: nonstandard or highly colloquial
見せる = to show


顔(を)見れる自信(が)なかった
I wasn't sure I can see his face (because I was embarrassed, ashamed, afraid, etc).

